# How to run sparql using jena elephas and spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jena

I want do sparql on data which is stored in hdfs or data in rdd variable using jena elephas and spark.

I tried below to read rdf file and store it in rdd.

```
val factory = new RdfXmlReaderFactory()
HadoopRdfIORegistry.addReaderFactory(factory)
val conf = new Configuration()
conf.set("rdf.io.input.ignore-bad-tuples", "false")
val path = "twitter.rdf"
val data = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path,
              classOf[RdfXmlInputFormat],
              classOf[LongWritable], 
              classOf[TripleWritable],   
              conf)
```

How to do sparql query on above data ?
thanks in advance..

Comment: Elephas is only intended to provide basic support for RDF data formats in Hadoop, it doesn't provide any SPARQL support